# How can I configure Ubuntu 16.04 (LTS) to develop GStreamer applications

Tags: linux, gstreamer-1.0

I am not able to find the gst.h header file on my Ubuntu environment after the installation of GStreamer packages.

Where do I find the gst.h file so I can build an application with it?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a challenge to find any detailed descriptions on how to install GStreamer libraries to build applications on Linux:

The initial command:

$ sudo apt-get install **libgstreamer1.0-dev** **libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev** gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio

The official documentation here: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html is not describing this *-dev option. Basically you need the libgstreamer1.0-dev to have access to the header file called gst.h (/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gst.h)

As of January 22, 2019, I had to downgrade three libraries to be able to install the *-dev GStreamer libraries on Ubuntu 16.04LTS (you may or may not need to downgrade).

You will know if you need to downgrade when you type: $ sudo aptitude install libgstreamer1.0-dev   libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev

The libraries to downgrade are pointed out by aptitude:

- libglib2.0-dev depends on libglib2.0-0=2.48.0-1ubuntu4, I had 2.48.2-0Ubuntu4.1 installed instead.
- libxml2-dev depends on libxml2=2.9.3+dfsg1-1, I had 2.9.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.6 installed.
- libicu-dev depends on libicu55= 55.1-7 but I had 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 installed.

The three commands below took care of the downgrade:

$ sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0=2.48.0-1ubuntu4

$ sudo apt-get install libxml2=2.9.3+dfsg1-1

$ sudo apt-get install libicu55=55.1-7

Now if you run: $ sudo find / -name gst.h

You should get now the header file used for development: /usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gst.h

Also this command here: $ pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0

returns: -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0

Comment: On Ubuntu and Debian, if you need to develop against any package, you almost always need to install a -dev version of the package. Their documentation fails to.mention it for some reason. They do mention the corresponding thing for Fedora.